# Should I vote to close my post or change it to be substantially different from the original?

Tags: discussion

[Can you change the font size of some of a bootstrap page without screwing up the layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284675/can-you-change-the-font-size-of-some-of-a-bootstrap-page-without-screwing-up-the)

So I wrote this based on a misunderstanding of how bootstrap layout was working - I only saw the layout change when I changed the font but it turns out that it was a complete coincidence.

I investigated and realised that and have spent a load of time editing the question.

None of the current answers seem to grasp that it is about layout and my own answer feels unsatisfactory.

---

I don't feel like its a good question at the moment as it contains it's own answer and is probably a bit confusing as a result of my own confusion.

Should I vote to close it?  As pointed out by @mega6382 I can't delete it myself as it has too many answers

The other alternative I can think of is to change it so that it asks "Why is bootstrap not maintaining equal margins when content spills over and how do I fix that?"

I could then post what I've learned about the layout but it wouldn't really answer the question.... I'm also not interested in other replies anymore as I've already solved the problem by using a full width layout, which just avoids the problem alltogether.

Changing the question would completely invalidate all the current answers about font size.  But it turned out that font size wasn't actually important to the question.

Thoughts?!

Comment: There are also already a couple of close flags on there... but I think at the moment it's only useful to me so I think deletion would be better

Comment: You, cant delete it anyway, because there are more than 1 answers on it.

Comment: @mega6382 I can see the delete button, I assumed that meant It'd work

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Comment: @mega6382 haha I feel like this is getting truly meta now... maybe I should change _this_ question to say 'vote to close my own post'